# How to add a 'Define Condition' section to a value help in a UI5 SmartFilter?

Tags: odata, sapui5

App UI5 Version: 1.44

I have enhanced a standard oData Service and added a custom field to one of the entities. Then I created an annotation to enable a value help for this custom field to be used in a UI5 SmartFilter.

Annotations:

```
<Property Name="ZBrandId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="60" sap:filter-restriction="multi-value" sap:label="Marke" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false"/>
```

```
<Annotations xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Target="DMF.PROD_MD_SRV.ProductFilter/ZBrandId">
    <Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.ValueList">
        <Record>
            <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath" String="SH_HZCA_H_BRAND_CDS"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="SearchSupported" Bool="true"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
                <Collection>
                    <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.ValueListParameterInOut">
                        <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="ZBrandId"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="BRAND_ID"/>
                    </Record>
                    <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly">
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="BRAND_DESCR"/>
                    </Record>
                </Collection>
            </PropertyValue>
        </Record>
    </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

When I execute the value help for this custom field I get a search dialogue that shows me a list of values that I can choose from. It looks like this:

[ValueList without exclude option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7tWP.png)

However, I was hoping to also have the option of being able to define conditions, meaning to exclude values, similar to this:

[ValueList with exclude option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDh9d.png)

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If a field allowe dmultile values to be filters, then the condition tabs appears automatcially.
Write annotation for filter selectionType: MultileValue
sample code:

```
data : lo_annotation  type ref to /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_annotation,
   lo_property    type ref to /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_property,
   lo_entity_set  type ref to /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_entity_set,
   lo_entity_type type ref to /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_entity_typ.
try .
    "make plant mandatory and single value
    lo_entity_type = model->get_entity_type( iv_entity_name = gc_pidocument ).
    lo_property = lo_entity_type->get_property( iv_property_name = 'Plant' ).

lo_annotation->add( iv_key   = 'filter-restriction'
                    iv_value = 'multile-value' ).



 catch /iwbep/cx_mgw_med_exception  .
endtry.
```

Comment: I set 'sap:filter-restriction="multi-value"' for the property as can be seen in the metadata.xml clip shown in my post. Still, no 'exclude' section is offered by the value help.